# Utiliser "J'espérais" sans sous-entendre la réalisation ou non de l'évènement ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Pour décrire mes attentes avant un évènement, j'ai utilisé "*J'espérais découvrir...*", mais je trouve que cette formulation implique que finalement, ce n'est pas arrivé.

J'aimerais parler de mes attentes sans donner d'information sur si ces attentes ont été réalisées ou non, c'est une phrase que je veux mettre dans une introduction.

Que pensez-vous de cette formulation, est-elle problématique ? Comment auriez-vous tourné la phrase pour laisser un suspense total ? (Ou faute de mieux, sous-entendre que les attentes ont bien été réalisées).

Je pense à des choses comme "*Mon but/objectif était de...*" mais le même problème se pose, et ça fait un peu trop "compétitif" pour mon sujet.

<sub>D'ailleurs si quelqu'un a un meilleur mot que "*réaliser*" pour aller avec "*attentes*" je suis preneur. "*Remplir*" ne me satisfait pas et je ne sais pas trop comment utiliser "*répondre à*" en utilisant la forme passive ("Mes attentes ont été ___")</sub>

**Un peu de contexte :**
J'essaie souvent d'être général pour ne pas restreindre les réponses à mon cas seulement, mais c'est vrai que parfois ça rend difficile de répondre correctement.

Je parle au présent d'un voyage que j'ai fait. J'avais des attentes avant le voyage assez ciblées (rencontrer les populations locales, m'initier à la culture, élargir mon point de vue, m'enrichir personnellement, etc.), et au moment ou je parle, le voyage est terminé, je sais que ces attentes ont été réalisées.

Comment: Est-ce que vous pourriez fournir plus de contexte? Cela aiderait grandement pour chercher une formule appropriée.

Comment: I'll be thinking about this more, because it seems like it's a cross-linguistic question if anything. It may be related to [Grice's maxims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle) or focus-shifting. (Consider that in English, the phrase "I was hoping you would *come* today" means the person did not come, but "I was *hoping* you would come today" means the person did come.) If I come up with anything more useful than this speculation, I'll add an answer...

Comment: Déplacer *l'intention* sur *l'action* « Partir vers ce pays et découvrir non seulement villes et paysages, mais surtout les personnes et l'art d'y vivre [voilà {mon/un/le but}/{ma/une/la} motivation, | un rêve/un souhait/une envie |  qui me tenaille/m'obsède/me stimule/s'est emparé de moi. » … ou autre incises.

Answer (score 4):

« J'espérais découvrir… » est en effet un indicateur fort d'un espoir déçu, encore qu'il peut quand même être utilisé pour introduire un rebondissement :

> Au début du tournoi, j'espérais découvrir une équipe de foot capable de se qualifier pour la finale, et bien, je n'ai pas été déçu, elle l'a même gagnée !

Sinon, il n'est pas facile de proposer une réponse complète car la question ne précise aucun contexte et les suggestions qui y sont proposées sont toutes tronquées mais voici ce que je pourrais écrire :

> Je … pour vérifier/confirmer/m'assurer que…

---

Suite à l'ajout du contexte à la question, voici une autre proposition qui décrit les attentes de l'auteur sans présager de la suite :

> J'ai entrepris ce voyage avec l'ambition de rencontrer les populations locales, m'initier à leur culture,…

Comment: Je suis d'accord pour plus de contexte.

Comment: @Frank J'ai corrigé, mais je suis finalement dubitatif. « Souhaiter » est suivi du conditionnel « je souhaitais qu'elle se qualifie (qualifiât) pour la finale », pourquoi pas « espérer » qui signifie sensiblement la même chose ? (j'ai depuis remanié la phrase car il y manquait « découvrir »).

Comment: oui - cela illustre probablement deux phénomènes: qu'il y a plusieurs solutions possibles, et que des fois on se perd dans ces accords de temps, subjonctifs et autres conditionnels (en tout cas pour moi), ce qui explique pourquoi l'usage tend à les simplifier :-)

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,

Je vous propose "J'avais l'espoir de découvrir", "J'aspirais à découvrir", "Je souhaitais découvrir". 
Il est possible de transformer ces mêmes propositions de la manière suivante: 
"Mon espoir était de découvrir", "Mon aspiration était de découvrir", "Mon souhait était de découvrir".

Pourquoi pas également "Ma finalité était de découvrir".

En ce qui concerne le mot réaliser pour "réaliser mes attentes", il y a le verbe "satisfaire"  qui est dans une note moins optimiste il est vrai. Je vous propose "matérialiser", "combler" (en fonction du sujet de votre introduction) ou alors de changer le mot attente pour quelque chose comme "J'ai accompli mon objectif". Il faudrait plus de détails pour savoir s'il serait possible de dire "J'ai réussi à" ou "Je n'ai pas été déçu".

Comment: Merci de tes propositions. Je trouve toujours que "*J'avais l'espoir*" et "*J'aspirais*" donne l'idée que je n'ai pas réussi. J'ai remarqué que le passé tourne plus la phrase vers le *réalisé*, ex: "*Mon objectif **était** de decouvrir*" vs "*Mon objectif **a été** de découvrir*"

Comment: Passé composé* pardon.

Answer (score 1):

Est-ce que ce n'est pas le temps passé qui introduit la notion qu'il n'y a pas eu de réalisation? Sinon (sans utiliser *espérer*, qui, combiné avec un passé donne probablement l'impression que l'espoir ne s'est pas réalisé - il faut peut-être s'éloigner de *espérer, souhaiter, attendre*):

> Mon intention était de comprendre si ...
>
> Mon intention était de vérifier si ...
>
> J'avais l'intention de vérifier si ...
>
> Je voulais vérifier ...
>
> Je voulais comprendre ...

Sans parler *d'attentes*. Ca fait un peu plus "scientifique", comme si vous aviez fait une expérience sans attente particulière, et c'est peut-être acceptable si vous vous apprêtiez à utiliser *découvrir*?

Ou alors, on pourrait être explicite:

> Sans attente particulière, j'espérais pouvoir découvrir ...

Encore une autre possibilité (après ajout du contexte par l'OP):

> Au cours de ce voyage, je pensais découvrir la culture ...

Comment: Également : Je visais ...

Answer (score 0):

Vos attentes expriment un désir sans savoir pour autant s'il va se réaliser ou pas. Et vous souhaitez que l'issue demeure inconnue.

Je suggère donc la formulation suivante:

> Je voudrais découvrir ...

exemple:

> **Je voudrais découvrir** une loi qui viendrait expliquer ce phénomène.

Comment: Oui, mais je crois que le récit se déroule dans le passé...

Comment: Bien vu Frank, j'espérais est à l'imparfait donc l'évènement s'est déroulé au passé. Mais l'auteur veut décrire ses attentes avant que l'évènement ne se produise, et il utilise l'imparfait, alors qu'il aurait du utiliser le conditionnel. Voilà pourquoi j'ai utilisé le conditionnel.

Comment: @sapienz L'évènement s'est déjà passé, il est terminé. Je connais les résultats, mais je ne veux pas les dévoiler tout de suite. Le récit lui-même est au présent, mais comme l'évènement est terminé, son début et sa fin sont à décrire au passé.

Comment: @Teleporting Goat Le temps utilisé dans votre récit est l'imparfait qui est souvent utilisé pour planter le décor d'un récit et sa description. Pour la narration, les temps priviligiés sont le passé composé, le présent de narration et le passé simple.

Comment: @sapienz Excuse-moi, mais quand je dis que mon récit est au présent, tu n'as pas à me dire qu'il est à l'imparfait. Ma phrase est à l'imparfait. Tu n'as juste pas assez d'information pour déterminer le temps du récit. Quand je dis : "J'aime bien le Brésil. Avant d'y aller, je ne savais pas trop à quoi m'attendre, mais le voyage s'est très bien passé et j'en garde un bon souvenir. Parfois je me dis que j'aimerais bien y retourner, mais j'ai tellement d'autres endroits à visiter.", le récit est au présent.

Comment: @sapienz Dans un récit au passé, tous les temps sont au passé. Qu'on parle d'évènements se passant avant ou après le moment dont on parle, on utilise un temps du passé. Dans un récit au présent, on utilise beaucoup plus de temps différents, passé simple, imparfait, futur. C'est pas parce qu'une phrase est à l'imparfait que le récit est au passé. Je n'avais pas eu le temps d'ajouter du contexte, je vais le faire pour éviter que tout le monde parte dans une direction différente.

Answer (score 0):

En anglais, j’emploierais « [With this voyage,] I was **trying** to … » pour essayer de réduire (un peu)  l’implication négative qui, d’après moi, existe aussi avec « I **wanted** to … » en anglais (peut-être que j’ai tort, mais il me semble que « I wanted to … [but] » implique qu’un « but » va suivre plus souvent que « I was trying to … [but] »).
 Donc, peut-être même en français, peut-être en remplaçant « vouloir » avec « essayer [de] » vous pourriez rester plus neutre en ce qui concerne le/s résultat/s sans trop changer le sens de l’introduction (souvent on essaie de faire X car on veut faire X ?) :

[Avec ce project/voyage] J’essayais/J’ai essayé [de] découvrir … .

Mon but/objectif était d’essayer [de] découvrir …